# How to center an image and button to another button

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to center an image and button to another button. I do not know how to do this. It would be appreciated if someone can show me through the storyboard interface and not code. Thanks

I tried selecting both and control dragging it to the button I want it to center with. However, it just center the button rather than both.

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2572/8M6NRu.png

As you can see, I want to center the lock image and already have an account button to the get started button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't center a pair-of-views. So you need *another* view that does nothing but contain the lower lock-and-button, and now you *can* center *that* in respect to the upper button.

This use of an effectively invisible view just to make the layout constraints work correctly is extremely common, so don't hesitate.

You will need to pin the lower lock-and-button on all four sides to their superview, the new view that I'm talking about, in order to size the new view to fit them. Then you position the new view and you're all set.

In the storyboard:

[image]

In the running app:

[image]